# Display saved files of NSHomeDirectory() in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

In my app , I have to store some data, for that purpose I used the `NSHomeDirectory`and  Stored the data into it with the documents folder.
i.e

`NSString *filename = [[[URL1 path] lastPathComponent] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

> NSString *Path=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/"];

`result=[Path stringByAppendingString:filename];`

Now I wish to display this data into the UITableView,
How it is possible
And I search regarding this and come to know`NSDocumentDirectory` ..How NSHomeDirectory is different from this??
 i got this answer

```
-(void)setUpTheFileNamesToBeListed{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [filePathsArray count];   
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


//Insert this line to add the file name to the list
cell.textLabel.text = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

This is what i got..
But how it will work for me..for the NSHomeDirectory.

Answer (score 2):

in the code above change

```
-(void)setUpTheFileNamesToBeListed{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
}
```

to this

```
-(void)setUpTheFileNamesToBeListed{
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/"];
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
}
```